# How to Spring for AWS S3 , The image takes too long to upload

Tags: java, spring, maven, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

16MB image takes 20 seconds to upload...
It takes three minutes to upload 20 images.

I do not know the exact cause.
The code I wrote.

Spring 4.1.7 + JAVA8 + Tomcat7.0.64

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
        <version>1.10.32</version>
    </dependency>
```

AWS S3 init

```
AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey);
            ClientConfiguration clientConfig = new ClientConfiguration();
            clientConfig.setProtocol(Protocol.HTTP);
            this.amazonS3Client = new AmazonS3Client(credentials, clientConfig);
    //      this.amazonS3Client.setEndpoint("ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com");
            this.amazonS3Client.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.fromName(region)));
```

AWS S3 Upload code

```
    private PutObjectResult upload(InputStream inputStream, String uploadKey, ObjectMetadata metadata) {
            PutObjectRequest putObjectRequest = new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, uploadKey, inputStream, metadata);
            putObjectRequest.setCannedAcl(CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead);
            PutObjectResult putObjectResult = amazonS3Client.putObject(putObjectRequest);
            IOUtils.closeQuietly(inputStream);
            return putObjectResult;
        }
```

Delays code

```
PutObjectResult putObjectResult = amazonS3Client.putObject(putObjectRequest);
```

Parameter

```
putObjectResults.resultData.add(upload(multipartFile.getInputStream(), tempName, metadata));
```

Data receiving part

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/upload" , method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public Object actionProfileUpdate(HttpServletRequest request){
        multipartRequest =  (MultipartHttpServletRequest)request;

        files = new ArrayList<MultipartFile>();
        files.add(multipartRequest.getFiles("ImageFile").get(0));

        MultipartFile[] multipartFiles = files.toArray(new MultipartFile[files.size()]);
        ResultUploadS3VO resultUUploadData = s3.upload(multipartFiles);
```

I do not know why. Please help me.. T.T

Comment: Where are you running this code? On an Amazon EC2 instance?

Comment: @mbaird no EC2,   IDC server

Comment: Try using a command line tool to copy something to S3 on the same server, to determine if it is your code that is the problem or your network connection to S3 that is the problem. I don't know what an IDC server is, but if you aren't running your code from AWS I don't think you have any guarantees that communication with S3 is going to be fast.

Comment: Server sending the file is located in the Internet data center.
The server itself.

I'll try to test in AWS EC2!
thk.

Comment: @mbaird Local, IDC, AWS EC2 same test results
Have you ever haneunge haejwoya set in the spring?